# How to use a trained SegFormer model on a single image?

Tags: python, pytorch, semantic-segmentation, pytorch-lightning

I trained a SegFormer model using the `fit` method of the `Trainer` class.

```
segformer_finetuner = SegformerFinetuner(
    train_dataset.id2label,
    train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloader=val_dataloader,
    test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
    metrics_interval=10,
)

early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss",
    min_delta=0.00,
    patience=10,
    verbose=False,
    mode="min",
)

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(save_top_k=1, monitor="val_loss")

trainer = pytorch_lightning.Trainer(
    gpus=1,
    callbacks=[early_stop_callback, checkpoint_callback],
    max_epochs=500,
    val_check_interval=len(train_dataloader),
)
trainer.fit(segformer_finetuner)
```

I got a checkpoints file `epoch=151-step=304.ckpt` as output, but I don't know how to use it to predict for a single image.

I tried like this:

```
model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('lightning_logs/version_33/checkpoints/epoch=151-step=304.ckpt'))
model.eval()

# Load the image
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
img = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='path/to/image', transform=transform)
img = img.unsqueeze(0)

# Make the prediction
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(img)
```

But I think I'm moving in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Checkpoint file you are trying to load is a dictionary. What you are looking for is loading the value in "state_dict". This worked for me:

```
checkpoint = torch.load(<your checkpoint file path here>)
state_dict = checkpoint["state_dict"]
model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation() 
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
model.eval()
```

and then you are ready to use the model as you tried:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(img)
```

Comment: Yes, and use the output via Softmax, or whatever. OP, you are on the correct direction.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried to do what you suggested. but I got an error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'` on the line `model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as @alex above with TypeError:
`__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'`

below is the code that worked for me to train and then predict a SegformerForSemanticSegmentation model. Note that for my purposes I needed to set a very high feature extraction number. This can be greatly reduced depending on use case
`feature_extractor.size = 2**10 # 128 is the default value`

## TRAINING

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
from datasets import load_metric
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.early_stopping import EarlyStopping
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint import ModelCheckpoint
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import SegformerForSemanticSegmentation, SegformerImageProcessor


class SemanticSegmentationDataset(Dataset):
    """Image (semantic) segmentation dataset."""

    def __init__(self, root_dir, feature_extractor):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.feature_extractor = feature_extractor

        # get the filenames of the images and labels
        self.masks = sorted([str(x) for x in Path(root_dir).glob("*_mask.png")])
        self.images = [x.replace("_mask.png", ".png") for x in self.masks]

        self.id2label = {0: "background", 1: "mask"}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.images[idx]))
        segmentation_map = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.masks[idx]))

        encoded_inputs = self.feature_extractor(
            image, segmentation_map, return_tensors="pt"
        )

        for k, v in encoded_inputs.items():
            encoded_inputs[k].squeeze_()

        return encoded_inputs


class SegformerFinetuner(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        id2label,
        train_dataloader=None,
        val_dataloader=None,
        test_dataloader=None,
        metrics_interval=100,
    ):
        super(SegformerFinetuner, self).__init__()
        self.id2label = id2label
        self.metrics_interval = metrics_interval
        self.train_dl = train_dataloader
        self.val_dl = val_dataloader
        self.test_dl = test_dataloader

        self.num_classes = len(id2label.keys())
        self.label2id = {v: k for k, v in self.id2label.items()}

        self.model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained(
            base_model,
            return_dict=False,
            num_labels=self.num_classes,
            id2label=self.id2label,
            label2id=self.label2id,
            ignore_mismatched_sizes=True,
        )

        self.train_mean_iou = load_metric("mean_iou")
        self.val_mean_iou = load_metric("mean_iou")
        self.test_mean_iou = load_metric("mean_iou")

    def forward(self, images, masks):
        outputs = self.model(pixel_values=images, labels=masks)
        return outputs

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        images, masks = batch["pixel_values"], batch["labels"]

        outputs = self(images, masks)

        loss, logits = outputs[0], outputs[1]

        upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
            logits, size=masks.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False
        )

        predicted = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)

        self.train_mean_iou.add_batch(
            predictions=predicted.detach().cpu().numpy(),
            references=masks.detach().cpu().numpy(),
        )
        if batch_nb % self.metrics_interval == 0:
            metrics = self.train_mean_iou.compute(
                num_labels=self.num_classes,
                ignore_index=255,
                reduce_labels=False,
            )

            metrics = {
                "loss": loss,
                "mean_iou": metrics["mean_iou"],
                "mean_accuracy": metrics["mean_accuracy"],
            }

            for k, v in metrics.items():
                self.log(k, v)

            return metrics
        else:
            return {"loss": loss}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        images, masks = batch["pixel_values"], batch["labels"]

        outputs = self(images, masks)

        loss, logits = outputs[0], outputs[1]

        upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
            logits, size=masks.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False
        )

        predicted = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)

        self.val_mean_iou.add_batch(
            predictions=predicted.detach().cpu().numpy(),
            references=masks.detach().cpu().numpy(),
        )

        return {"val_loss": loss}

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        metrics = self.val_mean_iou.compute(
            num_labels=self.num_classes,
            ignore_index=255,
            reduce_labels=False,
        )

        avg_val_loss = torch.stack([x["val_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        val_mean_iou = metrics["mean_iou"]
        val_mean_accuracy = metrics["mean_accuracy"]

        metrics = {
            "val_loss": avg_val_loss,
            "val_mean_iou": val_mean_iou,
            "val_mean_accuracy": val_mean_accuracy,
        }
        for k, v in metrics.items():
            self.log(k, v)

        return metrics

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        images, masks = batch["pixel_values"], batch["labels"]

        outputs = self(images, masks)

        loss, logits = outputs[0], outputs[1]

        upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
            logits, size=masks.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False
        )

        predicted = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)

        self.test_mean_iou.add_batch(
            predictions=predicted.detach().cpu().numpy(),
            references=masks.detach().cpu().numpy(),
        )

        return {"test_loss": loss}

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        metrics = self.test_mean_iou.compute(
            num_labels=self.num_classes,
            ignore_index=255,
            reduce_labels=False,
        )

        avg_test_loss = torch.stack([x["test_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        test_mean_iou = metrics["mean_iou"]
        test_mean_accuracy = metrics["mean_accuracy"]

        metrics = {
            "test_loss": avg_test_loss,
            "test_mean_iou": test_mean_iou,
            "test_mean_accuracy": test_mean_accuracy,
        }

        for k, v in metrics.items():
            self.log(k, v)

        return metrics

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(
            [p for p in self.parameters() if p.requires_grad], lr=2e-05, eps=1e-08
        )

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return self.train_dl

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return self.val_dl

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return self.test_dl


def plot_predictions(dataloader):
    predicted_lst = []
    truth_lst = []
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
        images, masks = batch["pixel_values"], batch["labels"]
        outputs = segformer_finetuner.model(images, masks)

        loss, logits = outputs[0], outputs[1]

        upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
            logits, size=masks.shape[-2:], mode="bilinear", align_corners=False
        )

        predicted_lst.append(upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1).cpu().numpy())
        truth_lst.append(masks.cpu().numpy())

    for p, t in zip(predicted_lst, truth_lst):
        a = cv2.resize(p[0], dsize=(4040, 1533), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT)
        b = cv2.resize(t[0], dsize=(4040, 1533), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT)
        plt.imshow(np.vstack([a, b]), cmap="gray")
        plt.show()


for base_model in [
    # "nvidia/segformer-b0-finetuned-ade-512-512",
    # "nvidia/segformer-b3-finetuned-cityscapes-1024-1024",
    "nvidia/segformer-b2-finetuned-cityscapes-1024-1024",
]:
    feature_extractor = SegformerImageProcessor.from_pretrained(base_model)
    feature_extractor.do_reduce_labels = False
    feature_extractor.size = 2**10

    # NOTE that the directory below contains images where the base image is 
    # in the format blah.png and the relevant mask blah_mask.png

    pth = "<path to base images and masks>"
    train_dataset = SemanticSegmentationDataset(pth, feature_extractor)
    val_dataset = SemanticSegmentationDataset(pth, feature_extractor)
    test_dataset = SemanticSegmentationDataset(pth, feature_extractor)

    batch_size = 1
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=8,
        prefetch_factor=8,
    )
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(
        val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=3, prefetch_factor=8
    )
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(
        test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=3, prefetch_factor=8
    )

    segformer_finetuner = SegformerFinetuner(
        train_dataset.id2label,
        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
        val_dataloader=val_dataloader,
        test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
        metrics_interval=10,
    )

    early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(
        monitor="val_loss",
        min_delta=0.00,
        patience=5,
        verbose=False,
        mode="min",
    )

    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(save_top_k=1, monitor="val_loss")

    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        gpus=1,
        # callbacks=[early_stop_callback, checkpoint_callback],
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
        max_epochs=200,
        val_check_interval=len(train_dataloader),
    )

    trainer.fit(segformer_finetuner)

    res = trainer.test(ckpt_path="best")

    print(base_model)
    plot_predictions(train_dataloader)
```

## LOAD FROM CHECKPOINT AND PREDICT

```
from transformers import SegformerForSemanticSegmentation, SegformerImageProcessor
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch import nn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm


def load_model_from_trainer_checkpoint(
    base_model="nvidia/segformer-b2-finetuned-cityscapes-1024-1024",
    checkpoint="<path to checkpoint>.ckpt",
):
    id2label = {0: "background", 1: "mask"}
    label2id = {v: k for k, v in id2label.items()}

    model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained(
        base_model,
        return_dict=False,
        num_labels=2,
        id2label=id2label,
        label2id=label2id,
        ignore_mismatched_sizes=True,
    )

    feature_extractor = SegformerImageProcessor.from_pretrained(base_model)
    feature_extractor.do_reduce_labels = False
    feature_extractor.size = 2**10

    checkpoint_dict = torch.load(checkpoint)["state_dict"]
    checkpoint_dict = {k.replace("model.", ""): v for k, v in checkpoint_dict.items()}
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint_dict)

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    model = model.to(device)
    model.eval()

    return model, feature_extractor 


def predict_mask(model, feature_extractor, img_fname, plot_img=True):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    image = Image.open(img_fname)

    pixel_values = feature_extractor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(
            pixel_values
        )  # logits are of shape (batch_size, num_labels, height/4, width/4)

    # First, rescale logits to original image size
    upsampled_logits = nn.functional.interpolate(
        outputs[0],
        size=image.size[::-1],  # (height, width)
        mode="bilinear",
        align_corners=False,
    )

    # Second, apply argmax on the class dimension
    pred_seg = upsampled_logits.argmax(dim=1)[0].detach().cpu().numpy()

    mask = cv2.cvtColor((pred_seg).astype(np.uint8) * 255, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    if plot_img:
        plt.imshow(np.vstack([mask, image]))
        plt.show()

    return image, mask


model, feature_extractor = load_model_from_trainer_checkpoint()

for img_fname in tqdm(
    list(Path("<path to dir with images to infer>").glob("*.png"))
):
    image, mask = predict_mask(model, feature_extractor, img_fname, plot_img=True)
```